# My code search is really slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, search, full-text-search

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,MATCH (CUIT,DENOMINACION) AGAINST ('%{$word}%') AS Score FROM cuits WHERE";
$sql_end = '';
foreach($words as $word) {
    $sql_end .= " AND MATCH (CUIT,DENOMINACION) AGAINST ('%{$word}%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND BAJA=0 ";
    $sql_end2 = "order by DENOMINACION limit $inicio, $TAMANO_PAGINA";
}
```

It is very slow. How can I improve the speed?

Comment: What language are you using to do this searching in? It's not tagged here. If you want faster searching on arbitrary data, try using [full text search features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense in FULLTEXT search to use `LIKE`-style wildcard strings `%`.  So, change `AGAINST ('%{$word}%')` to `AGAINST ('{$word}')` and see if it helps.

Also, FULLTEXT can match multiple words at once, so there's no need to repeat the whole `MATCH` clause for each word.  Instead try

```
 SELECT *,MATCH (CUIT,DENOMINACION) AGAINST ('word word word word') ...
```

You may, if the series of words is a phrase, wish to stop using the boolean FULLTEXT mode and use the natural language mode as shown in your first `MATCH` clause.

Be aware that FULLTEXT works very strangely indeed on small tables, with less than a few hundred rows. That makes testing on small tables difficult.

Finally, make sure your FULLTEXT index is constructed correctly.